# Unable to call a method

Tags: xcode, methods, uiimage

I am trying to call the method below using  [self changeColor]; and getting

> "No visible interface for @MyClassViewController declares the selector "changeColor"

I did declare it like that on both .h and .m:

```
@interface changeColor 

- (UIImage *) changeColor:(UIImage *)image;

@end
```

What I am doing wrong?
Please help

-------------Code-------------

```
- (UIImage *) changeColor:(UIImage *)image 

{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    CGRect contextRect;
    contextRect.origin.x = 0.0f;
    contextRect.origin.y = 0.0f;
    contextRect.size = [image size];
    // Retrieve source image and begin image context
    CGSize itemImageSize = [image size];
    CGPoint itemImagePosition; 
    itemImagePosition.x = ceilf((contextRect.size.width - itemImageSize.width) / 2);
    itemImagePosition.y = ceilf((contextRect.size.height - itemImageSize.height) );

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Setup shadow
    // Setup transparency layer and clip to mask
    CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(c, NULL);
    CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextClipToMask(c, CGRectMake(itemImagePosition.x, -itemImagePosition.y, itemImageSize.width, -itemImageSize.height), [image CGImage]);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    NSLog(@"--------- METHOD DETECTED");//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> TEST
    /*
    switch (row)

    {   
        case 0:
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 1, 0, 0., 1);
            break;
    }   
    */

    contextRect.size.height = -contextRect.size.height;
    contextRect.size.height -= 15;
    // Fill and end the transparency layer
    CGContextFillRect(c, contextRect);
    CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(c);

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `[self changeColor];`.  `changeColor` and `changeColor:` are two different things.  If you define it as taking one parameter, you have to call it that way.